# VirtualBox 5.0.10 refuses to work on my Windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, virtualization

I used the older version of VirtualBox (5.0.4 I think) still last week, and I could open my VM's no problem. But I reinstalled my Visual Studio 2015 Community edition on Monday, and no my VM's does not want to work anymore. Reports back `VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)`

I had this problem right in the beginning just after I've upgraded to Windows 10, and installed VS2015. I found then that Hyper-V was running, and I've stopped the service and it was sorted. Something is grabbing VT-x and I don't know what it is. I've gone through all my processes, stopped services that is not critical, but I cannot get my VM's to start.

Is there anybody that can tell me of something that I can use that will tell me what is grabbing VT-x, or what services in windows 10 apart from Hyper-V can also grab VT-x, or for that matter VS2015. From what I've read people suggest that an android emulator grabbed the VT-x. But I'm not sure what to do anymore, and unless I have to uninstall the Universal development platform on VS2015 and totally uninstall Hyper-V, I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: The proper way to state that a problem has been solved, in Stack Exchange, is **not** to add SOLVED to the title, but to write the solution as an answer, then to accept your own answer.

Comment: Sorry guys :( was not intentional;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V needs to be uninstalled altogether. Does not help just to stop the services. Not sure how that works, but I got my VM's back on.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error while moving a VM to another older machine. I found a (temporary ? performance penalty) workaround on an older Computer was turn it off on the Virtual Machine:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm <vmname> --hwvirtex off
```

After trying various options here [VirtualBox Forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=58820&start=45)